Deploying a Go app using Fuego to a Lambda
I have a issue deploying a Go application that uses fuego as a router and handling middleware. Is it possible to use fuego when deploying a go application to Lambda?
using lambda.start(handler)
I have tested using fuegos handler but don't seems to work. Also created a handler to route traffic but doesn't seem to work.
{
  s := fuego.NewServer()
    lambda.Start(lambdaHandler(s))
}

func lambdaHandler(s *fuego.Server) func(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    return func(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
        httpRequest, err := convertAPIGatewayToHTTPRequest(req)
        if err != nil {
            return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: http.StatusInternalServerError, Body: err.Error()}, nil
        }

        recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()

        s.ServeHTTP(recorder, httpRequest)

        apiGatewayResponse, err := convertHTTPResponseToAPIGateway(recorder.Result())
        if err != nil {
            return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: http.StatusInternalServerError, Body: err.Error()}, nil
        }

        return apiGatewayResponse, nil
    }
}

Anyone that has a fix or another example to use for golang api managed by aws?

where is the convert functions?
